# Does anyone know why this deleteItem function isn't working onPress?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can't get this `deleteItem` to work. Everything looks good and its logging that it is receiving the prop but the **item isn't being removed** upon the click. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**App.js:**

```
const App = () => {

  const [item, setItems] = useState([
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: ''
    },
  ]);

  const addItems = (text) => {

    if (!text) {
      Alert.alert('Error', "How can I add something thats not there??", { text: 'ok' })
    } else {
      setItems(prevItems => {
        return [{ id: uuidv4(), name: text }, ...prevItems]

      })
    }
  }

  const deleteItem = (id) => {
    setItems((prev) => {
      return prev.filter(item => item.id !== id)

    })
    console.log('working');
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground source={background} style={styles.image}>
        <Header
          title="Gotta get this done!" />
        <AddItem
          addItem={addItems}
        />
        <FlatList
          data={item}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            if (item.name === null) {
              return (
                <Prompt />
              )
            } else {
              return (
                <ListItem item={item.name} deleteItem={deleteItem} />
              )
            }
          }}
        />
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  )
};
```

Here is my **`ListItem`** component. I pass in the `deleteItem` prop and call it below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
// import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/dist/FontAwesome';

const ListItem = ({ item, deleteItem }) => {


    return (

        <View style={styles.listItem}>
            <View style={styles.listItemView}>
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>
                    <Text>Remove</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListItem item={item.name} deleteItem={deleteItem} />
```

You're passing the `name` property as `item`. You probably meant to pass the item itself:

```
<ListItem item={item} deleteItem={deleteItem} />
```

Remember to then access the `.name` property in the `ListItem` component:

```
const ListItem = ({ item, deleteItem }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.listItem}>
            <View style={styles.listItemView}>
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.name}</Text>
                                            {/*   ^^^^  */}
            </View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>
                    <Text>Remove</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
};
```

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, here's a the component with PropTypes which will print an error in the console for you for the version in your question:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const ListItem = // ...

ListItem.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string
    id: PropTypes.string
  }).isRequired,
  deleteItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much. Been stuck on this for a while now. I knew it was something small. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it solved the problem! Be sure to take a look at [`PropTypes`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) - they'll catch problems like this for you in development in the future!

Comment: Nice! Ill check it out.

Comment: @GTJ82 I edited my answer to add an example of PropTypes, you'll just need to `npm i prop-types` - try it with the version in your question and the error will just jump at you :)

Comment: Perfect, this is very helpful.